# Highcharts series multiple z-index

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to have multiple z-indices for a series.  For example, z-index = 1 for the part of the series that is positive and z-index = 2 for the part of the series that is negative?

Comment: No. You would have to split the positive and negative parts into two different series if you want a different `zIndex`

Comment: that's what I thought, thanks!